# Xamarin Forms Picker Item source binding in Xaml

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I need to create states picker in my Xamarin Forms. I am using Xaml file for creating views.

Can any one help me to bind Picker in Xaml with item source?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The last time I checked there was no ItemSource binding property for the Picker in XAML. That said you should either do the binding in code or via a custom BindablePicker (e.g.: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/30801/xamarin-forms-bindable-picker)

Comment: thecoshman - sometimes we have no clue where to start and come here for advice/samples

Answer (score 2):

The XLabs has an excellent example of a bindable picker that I have used in several projects to great affect:

https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs

This will allow you to replicate the 'ItemsSource' functionality of the Listview.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do this in XAML, as you can see [here](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=T%3AXamarin.Forms.Picker).

You'll have to load the data up in the code behind, using either their regular API, or something like [this](https://gist.github.com/Sankra/286cfbdd5dfd379a9155).

You can also serialize your list as a JSON or preferred format, and deserialize that and pass it to the `Picker`.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality did not previous exist, but it was recently added to the regular Xamarin.Forms Picker via the new `ItemsSource` and `SelectedItem` properties. It is currently in the pre-release NuGet package for [version 2.3.4-pre1](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/releases/tag/beta-2.3.4-pre1), but should be in the stable 2.3.4+ versions once it is released.

Answer (score 0):

As JordanMazurke commented, XLabs has it.
Here is an example:

```
<ContentPage x:Class="XLabs.Samples.Pages.Controls.ExtendedPickerPage"
         xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XLabs.Forms.Controls;assembly=XLabs.Forms"
         Title="Picker">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout x:Name="myStackLayout">
        <Label Text="Xaml:" />
        <controls:ExtendedPicker x:Name="myPicker"
                                 DisplayProperty="FirstName"
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataList}"
                                 SelectedItem="{Binding TheChosenOne}" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```