# How to bind Picker in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: mvvm, xamarin

So I've been wanting to bind the items of two pickers in Xamarin.Forms to my ViewModel. I have mainly used binding for textfields, where I just write something like:

```
<Label Text="{Binding CurrentDate}" />
```

and simply by setting the binding context, defining a property in the viewmodel

```
    public System.DateTime CurrentDate{
        get { return currentDate; }
        set { currentDate = value; PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CurrentDate")); }
    }
```

I am done binding. Now I have two pickers. The pickers represent a map/dictionary. Dictionary>. "A" is mapped to {"1","2"} and "B" is mapped to {"4","5"}. The first picker should show "A" and "B" as options. The second one should display the values associated with the chosen value from the first picker.

So there are two questions. 1) How do I bind a picker? 2) How do I bind a picker that has data that depends on another pickers selection?

I tried

```
<Picker Items="{Binding ItemsA}"></Picker>
```

With a matching property

```
    public List<string> ItemsA
    {
        get { return itemsA;}
        set { itemsA = value;PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ItemsA")); }
    }
```

Am I missing out on something here? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You do the binding to selected item of the list, not to the list itself.

Comment: So you would not try to bind the data presented in the Picker? This might be updated during runtime in the model and should be reflected on in the view. How do you populate the list? Consider that this data might change during runtime. @DanyDaKur

Comment: Simmply arrenge your data in the form it would be easily accesable - I would reccomend to keep it in the Dictionary<Value1, List<ForValue1>>. Do binding of the first list to Value 1, and depending on selection - upload Source to the picker 2 from Dictionary.  @why_vincent

Comment: My current structure is Dictionary<TypeA,IEnumerable<TypeB>> but the question is how to do the binding. The other poster says it cannot be done without introducing a new Picker. The question is "How do I bind this data to a Picker?". Your answer is just "Bind.". Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood what you need to do - and I agree with other poster - you need second picker here

Comment: Thanks, both of you saying this is evidence enough that I should use another Picker.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin Forms Picker Item source binding in Xaml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004261/xamarin-forms-picker-item-source-binding-in-xaml)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This functionality is unfortunately missing from the standard component, but relatively easy to add as detailed at https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/30801/xamarin-forms-bindable-picker.  Using this derived component you will then be able to bind **ItemsSource** and **SelectedItem** properties.  It's also relatively easy to add WPF-like DisplayMemberPath and ValueMemberPath properties if required.

Comment: Really? I am a bit new to this but Mvvm for me is pretty much all or nothing. I see no point in having an almost-fully separated view. I'll check out this component. Very odd that such a basic graphical element does not support this. Is this true for most Xamarin.Forms components?

Comment: I agree - it did seem like a shocking omission when I first encountered it, but it's not the tip of an iceberg. With the addition of a BindablePicker control and a Repeater control (for repeating templated content based on an ItemsSource) I have found Xamarin Forms a pretty capable MVVM platform, especially in conjunction with the free DevExpress grid, and I have now relatively easily ported some substantial Microsoft XAML based applications without too many compromises.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this functionality is built into the regular Xamarin.Forms Picker now. It is currently in the pre-release NuGet package for [version 2.3.4-pre1](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/releases/tag/beta-2.3.4-pre1), but should be in the stable 2.3.4+ versions once it is released. Instead of binding to Items you bind to `ItemsSource` and `SelectedItem`.

Comment: its released now!